# ST Monad usage outside of `do` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I see lots of examples of ST monad in the context of `do` notation; however since that's not suitable to my purpose, I try to use ST monad for instance `newSTRef` and `modifySTRef` outside of `do` thread.

The type is automatically added by HLS of VSCode.

```
ref :: ST s (STRef s Integer)
ref = newSTRef (1)

x :: ST s ()
x = modifySTRef ref 2
```

error: `ref` in the last line

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘STRef s a0’
            with actual type ‘ST s0 (STRef s0 Integer)’
```

Well, sure I can see the error saying the type doesn't match, but I don't know how to fix it.

What is the proper usage of ST Monad outside of `do`?

EDIT:

My purpose without `do` is

1. like the one mentioned, `do` is merely a syntax sugar and often I'd like to avoid it in order to write a code in more straightforward functional way.
2. The purpose to obtain the mutable object is to develop FRP, and the sequential definition and updates of `ref` in the single `do` thread is not useful for the purpose.

Comment: `x = ref >>= flip modifySTRef 2` is probably the closest thing to what you wrote that will compile, but it almost certainly won't do what you want. Can you explain why you don't think you can use `do` blocks, and provide more details of what the rest of your code would look like without them?

Comment: `STRef`s are local to the `runST` they're executed in. It makes no sense to have it any other way. Looks like you've got an X/Y problem here. Please tell us what you want to achieve. (Global variables? Those don't exist in Haskell.)

Comment: `do` is a syntactic sugar for a chain of function applications. It isn't clear how mere syntax may or may not be suitable for one's purposes.

Comment: Thank you guys, I modified my question. Actually, @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica comment might be enough for my question. Please answer as it is. I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Oh ok sure, I found that's the problem. Even I can mutate the `ref` , it's not possible to `runST(ref)`.

Comment: @Functor Indeed. A main point of `ST` is to guarantee that after `runST` no references remain alive. If you have `x :: ST s T`, you can run `runST x` only if `T` does not involve `s` -- the type of `ref` has `T = STRef s Integer` so it does involve `s` hence `runST` can not be used on it.

Comment: @chi Thanks for your input, so I guess ST Monad is unusable to obtain genine mutable objects to develop FRP, and I guess the only chance would be `IORef` & `unsafePerformIO`.

Comment: You may require unsafePerformIO, but unless you hide it behind your own monadic interface, it has a high chance of being unsafe, as the name promises.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you want to write FRP, take a look at some of the existing FRP libraries on Hackage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that `modifySTRef` takes an `STRef s a`, not a `ST s (STRef s a)`. `ST` was designed to utilize monad properties to secure mutable operations from being abused, so all modifications can happen only in an `ST` context. Therefore, you need to use the powers of the context to extract the pure `STRef` reference.

Normally you would `do` it like this:

```
x :: ST s ()
x = do
  refv <- ref
  modifySTRef refv 2
```

But since you would like to avoid this sugar, you can do right what it desugars to:

```
x :: ST s ()
x = refv >>= \refv -> modifySTRef refv 2
```

You can read more about the `do` notation and how it is resolved [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation)

---

Remark from the comments: note that your code does **not** have a global variable this way. `newSTRef` allocates a new piece of RAM **each time it is called in the ST context**. Therefore, `x` in this example does practically nothing (aside from wasting some memory and GC time).

If your intention was to keep the reference, you must carry it "in your hands", for example in a `ReaderT` wrapper.

Comment: Isn't your `x` not observably different than `pure ()`, despite being much slower?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Yes. In fact, it goes even further: all actions of type `ST s ()` are observably equivalent to `pure ()` (up to defined-ness).

Comment: Yes, good point. `ref` creates a new reference every time, so `x` essentially allocates a piece of memory, modifies it and throws it to garbage.